# PDF file(Multimedia Content) not getting deployed on CDS ,but is getting published successfully

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am using Tridion 2011 sp1.

My requirement is that on click of link "download PDF" a window should appear with options Save ,Cancel and Open.

First to publish PDF file.

I created a multimedia schema to upload pdf files.This pdf file is not included on page.
To publish the pdf to CDS I created a CT(Dynamic Component Template) with default finish Actions and placed a DWT TBB above this with code above Default Finish Actions in CT

```
<a href="" tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@" tridion:type="binary">link</a>
```

I associated pdf schema to CT and then published PDF Component.

But PDF is not getting deployed at CDS side.

I am able to publish pages and Images(these are present on Page) successfully.

Comment: When you say not deploying on CDS Side, are you looking in the FS directory you specified in your cd_stroage_conf.xml assuming you are using FS as your storage? Are you expecting this file to appear on page without including on the page ? If yes, then you need to write some code to get the pdf component dynamically using broker API.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to adjust your cd_stroage_conf.xml to make sure that binaries with the extension ".pdf' get placed in the same location as your images.

Look for a node like this

```
<Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension="pdf" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false"/>
```

and make sure it has the same storage location as the default binary storage like this:

```
<Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false"/>
```

Also check that  the priority of your CT is not set to 'Never Link'

Answer (score 0):

From SDLLiveContent regarding linking to a downloadable asset (in a MM component):

To create a hyperlink to the image file, which, on the published Web site, results in a hyperlink to the image resource, include code of the form

```
<a href="dummy.html" tridion:href="tcm:6-2" tridion:type="Multimedia">link text</a>
```

in the output. On the published page, this results in the output

```
<a href="pictures/Image01.jpg">link text</a>
```

, where pictures/Image01.jpg is your image file.